# new Date undefient en componente de React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Voy a sacar la fecha en un componente de de react y me aparece undefined

```
import React from 'react';


class componentDate extends React.Component {

  state = {
    date: null,
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.setState({date: this.date()});
  }



  date = () => {

    const date = new Date();
    console.log(date);
    const day = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    const currentDay = day[date.getDay()];
    return currentDay;

  }
   render() {

    return (
      <h2>{this.state.date}</h2>
    );

  }

}
```

me aparece que `getDay()` no es una función y hago el `console.log(date)` y me sale undefined, no entiendo por qué, si en otro component también tengo la fecha y me da el valor que es.

Comment: Tu código está bien,  probablemente se te esté pasando por alto que tenés comentada la linea donde seteas el estado, dentro de componentDidMount()

Comment: Lo que se está saltando es el constructor

Comment: No, lo tenía comentado para hacer una prueba pero se me paso descomentarlo y en otro componente que tengo tengo la fecha y no tengo constructor, ahí si como me funciona?

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';


class Date extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: null,
    }
    this.handleDate = this.handleDate.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.setState({date: this.handleDate()});
  }



  handleDate(){

    const date = new Date();
    console.log(date);
    const day = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    const currentDay = day[date.getDay()];
    return currentDay;

  }
   render() {

    return (
      <h2>{this.state.date}</h2>
    );

  }

}
```

Y por cierto, evita nombrar a los componentes y variables como palabras reservadas de Javascript, recuerda que Date está reservada, y tu componente se llama exactamente igual, es una mala idea.

Answer (score 0):

Con el React *clásico* no puedes acceder a las funciones que declares dentro del componente si no haces **binding** primero. Citando a la [documentación de React](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper):

> En JavaScript, los métodos de clase no están ligados por defecto. Si olvidas ligar this.handleClick y lo pasas a onClick, this será undefined cuando se llame la función.

Hay dos maneras de hacerlo, la primera es aplicar el *binding* directamente a la hora de llamar a tu función:

```
this.setState({date: this.handleDate.bind(this)});
//                                  ^ Aquí haces el binding
```

La otra es, utilizando el constructor, crear el *binding* para que exista como parte del componente:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ... };
    
    this.handleDate = this.handleDate.bind(this);
}
```

Adicionalmente, si no quieres usar `bind`, puedes usar una función flecha:

```
this.setState({ date: () => this.handleDate() });
```